# GIT <> SVN interchangeable patch-files

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I maintain a subproject which is running on the project's SVN server.
I personally prefer to work with Git - the problem is that the entire community uses SVN, expects RFCs with a SVN compatible patch-file and people are familiar with SVN and send bugfixes agains that SVN repository too.

Therefore my only problem is to create patch files which are compatible with Git and SVN at the same time.

Is there some kind of smart shell-script or even a buildin feature I'm not aware of?

Cheers

Comment: The problem, I respectfully submit, is that the project has one person who won't use the same toolset as everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the excellent [git-svn bridge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)? Besides that, patch files should be interchangeable in the most cases by default (git uses a new patch format with very few additions). If not you can switch git's patch format or delegate patch creation to another diff tool. See the [instructions](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: well I use git-svn but anyways before using "git svn dcommit" the mailinglist expects a (svn compatible) patch ... and the patches from "git format-patch" don't work with the some svn clients (e.g. TortoiseMerge) - but it seems that at least the "patch" on a regular Unix commandline works on them without complains